# How to prevent a PDF file from being indexed by search engines?

Tags: search-engine-indexing, pdf

I have a link to PDF document on a public web-page. How do I prevent search engines from indexing this link and PDF document?

The only idea I thought of is to use CAPTCHA.  However, I wonder if there are any magic words that tell a search engine to not index the link and PDF document?  Options using PHP or JavaScript are also fine.

Just to make it clear.  I do not want to encrypt PDF and protect it with password.  I just want to make it invisible for search engines, but not for users.

Comment: See also the following question if you want to prevent a _specific file_ from being indexed: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/132337/how-to-prevent-a-specific-pdf-file-from-being-indexed-by-search-engines-in-wordp

Comment: Here is an example of doing it the PHP way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71433606/386579

Answer (score 39):

To prevent your PDF file (or any non HTML file) from being listed in search results, the only way is to use the HTTP `X-Robots-Tag` response header, e.g.:

```
X-Robots-Tag: noindex
```

You can do this by adding the following snippet to the site's root .htaccess file or httpd.conf file:

```
<Files ~ "\.pdf$">
  Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
</Files>
```

Note that for the above to work, you must be able to modify the HTTP headers of the file in question. Thus you may not be able to do this, for example, on [GitHub Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798589/github-pages-http-headers).

Also note that *robots.txt* does **not** prevent your page from being listed in search results.

What it does is stop the bot from crawling your page, but if a third party links to your PDF file from *their* website, your page will still be listed.

If you stop the bot from crawling your page using *robots.txt*, it will not have the chance to see the `X-Robots-Tag: noindex` response tag. Therefore, never ever ever disallow a page in *robots.txt* if you employ the `X-Robots-Tag` header. More info can be found on [Google Developers: Robots Meta Tag](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag).

Comment: I don't follow how robots.txt with an entry for the page would prevent the X-Robots-Tag to be respected/obeyed if the page with that X-Robots-Tag was requested in the future.

Comment: I thought that when the page is requested, it("Google") would see the X-Robots-Tag header, and then know not to index it... but it looks like the X-Robots-Tag is only useful for crawlers which then know not to index it https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag#combining-crawling-with-indexing--serving-directives

Comment: Since you are using the regex enabled `Files` directive, you should consider using instead `FilesMatch` instead, as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/q/14792381/1262357

Comment: @Gruber Although there's no need to use "the regex enabled `Files` directive" here in the first place. The ordinary `<Files>` directive with a wildcard can be used to match all `.pdf` files (which seems to be the intention here). eg. `<Files "*.pdf">` - which is arguably preferable in this situation.

Answer (score 19):

There are multiple ways to do this (combining them is obviously a sure way to accomplish this):

1) Use *robots.txt* to block the files from search engines crawlers:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /pdfs/ # Block the /pdfs/directory.
Disallow: *.pdf  # Block pdf files. Non-standard but works for major search engines.
```

2) Use `rel="nofollow"` on links to those PDFs

```
<a href="something.pdf" rel="nofollow">Download PDF</a>
```

3) Use the `x-robots-tag: noindex` HTTP header to prevent crawlers from indexing them. Place this code in your *.htaccess* file:

```
<FilesMatch "\.pdf$">
  header set x-robots-tag: noindex
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Counterintuitively, using both `x-robots-tag` and `robots.txt` at the same time is not a good idea and may cause the content to be indexed anyways. If you use both `robots.txt` and `x-robots-tag: noindex`, the crawler will never crawl or see the `x-robots-tag` because it first honors the `robots.txt`. `robots.txt` does not prevent resources from being indexed, only from being crawled, so the best solution is to use the `x-robots-tag` header, yet allow the search engines to crawl and find that header by leaving your `robots.txt` alone.

Answer (score 2):

If you nginx powered development instances are showing up in Google search results, there is a quick and easy way to prevent search engines from crawling your site. Add the following line to the location block of your virtualhost configuration file for the block that you want to prevent crawling.

```
add_header  X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow, nosnippet, noarchive";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use *robots.txt* file. You can read more [here](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html).

Comment: Using robots.txt does not prevent *indexing*. It only prevents *crawling*. See [Pacerier](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/49124/33777)'s answer for correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this sill might bring some value to anyone, but we have recently encountered a problem that our on-premise GSA box is unwilling to index PDF file.

Google Support worked with the issue and their response is that it is related to the fact that this PDF document has a custom property set (File -> Document Properties -> Custom (tab))

```
name: robots
value: noindex
```

which prevented it from being properly indexed by GSA.

If you have access to the document and can modify it's properties this might work ... at lease for GSA.