# What are the htaccess mechanics of preventing search engines from indexing PDF files?

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing, pdf

There are already a variety of posts on how to block certain files (in my case, PDFs) from a search engine like Google. The most relevant for this post was here: [How to protect PDF file from indexing](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/14520/how-to-protect-pdf-file-from-indexing). However, in that post, the final answer was never quite clear. Based on these three sites:

- [Playing with the X-Robots-Tag](https://yoast.com/x-robots-tag-play/)
- [Preventing your site from being indexed, the right way](https://yoast.com/prevent-site-being-indexed/)
- [Google Developers Robots Meta Tag](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag)

I think I understand the recommendation. Essentially, we should *not* use robots.txt to disallow crawling/indexing of files. We should instead use X-Robots-Tag.

This brings me to three questions, which is really so I can be absolutely sure that what follows would work.

**Question 1:** Suppose I want to disallow search engine indexing to any files within a subfolder of my site, www.mysite.com/secret

I would create a .htaccess file in the subfolder with the following:

```
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
```

Alternatively, if I wish to disallow access in the secret subfolder only to PDFs, I would use (again within a separate .htaccess in the subfolder):

```
<FilesMatch ".doc$">
Header set X-Robots-Tag "index, noarchive, nosnippet"
</FilesMatch>
```

**Question 2:** Is there any advantage to doing the same for the main .htaccess file in the website root directory? If so, how do you alter the above two statements for subdirectories? On Google's site they suggest:

```
<Files ~ "\.pdf$">
  Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
</Files>
```

Do I change it to `"secret/\.pdf$"`instead? I am unsure of forward vs. backward slashes.

**Question 3:** Suppose I have a separate PDF document on a separate page that links the PDF in the secret folder. Even with the .htaccess x-robots tag block in place, does the third party linking break the non-indexing command?

Comment: Do you want to disallow *crawling* or *indexing*?

Comment: `Do you want to disallow crawling or indexing?` there's never any guarantee that Google or any other search bot won't crawl anything, even with blocks in robots, no index and no follow.

Comment: Out of interest why do you want to block PDF ?

Comment: I want to disallow indexing (that is, disallow results to show up in Google search or the equivalent). I want to block PDFs because they have sensitive information, and they also screw up other indexing schemes like Google Scholar citations. Basically, I want to share PDF preprints with other people (without a password), but don't want Google to display it in search results.

Comment: Then `<FilesMatch ".pdf$">` will stop Google indexing PDF's all together. You can reforce it with robots.txt if you wish but its not required unless your system goes AWOL and removes the x tag.

Comment: @SimonHayter You don't "reforce it with robots.txt" - if you block it with robots.txt then Google _should_ never even make the request and so would never see the "noindex" header.

Comment: @w3d Google can and does sometimes crawls blocked content in robots.txt. Even Google recommends you use no-index with robots.

Comment: @SimonHayter Whether Google "sometimes" crawls blocked-with-robots.txt content is irrelevant, the fact is that most-of-the-time it doesn't.  So, most of the time the `noindex` header would not be seen. Google recommends that when using `noindex` (meta tag _or_ HTTP response header), "the page **must not** be blocked by a robots.txt file." https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710?hl=en

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have done your research and seem to have a good handle on the situation.   To sum up:

Using *robots.txt* would prevent search engines from crawling the PDF files.   If third party sites linked directly to the PDF files, then search engines might include the URLs in the search index (but would still not be able to index their contents.)

Using `X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"` will prevent search engines from indexing the PDF files even though they may crawl them.  Third party sites directly linking to the files will still not cause the PDF files to get indexed.

You cannot use *both* methods.  If you block the PDF files with *robots.txt* search engines will never see the header and may still index the URLs.

---

Your first `FilesMatch` matching looks correct if you substitute `pdf` for `doc`.  The rule inside it looks like it would allow indexing, so you may have pasted in the wrong thing.

If you wanted to put it in the root directory you would need to use `secret/.*\.pdf$` instead.  The only advantage to doing so might be to centralize all your rules in one place.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to ask: is there a way to check whether the X-Robots-Tag is working properly, or do you have to wait and find out whether it pops up in searches?

Comment: Also, is it known whether indexing is enough to stop articles from showing up in Google Scholar? It does not seem to state here: https://scholar.google.co.uk/intl/en/scholar/inclusion.html Given what you have described, stopping Google from crawling is too difficult a task, so I would hope that Google Scholar will not include a page if there is a block to indexing.

Comment: I use command line tools such as curl to see the headers: `curl --head 'http:/example.com/secret/some.pdf'`

Comment: I've never worked with Google scholar.   I'd recommend asking "Does Google Scholar respect a X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow" header' as a separate question.

Comment: Stopping Google from crawling with robots.txt is 99% effective.   It only fails when a third party links to it, and even then it only shows up for keywords that are present in the URL or used in the anchor text of the links.  I've used robots.txt in conjunction with file names that change periodically.  That is very effective as well.

Comment: Aside from privacy benefits, is there strong reason to prefer a block on crawling vs. indexing? I suppose for my purposes, if I am worried about Google Scholar indexing, and I do not understand whether it respects an X-Robots-Tag command, then restricting the website from crawling is better. But now I am left confused as to what I should be doing. Your statement that "robots.txt is 99% effective" is clashing with the strong recommendations in the other stack exchange discussion to use X-Robots-Tag.

Comment: The percent effectiveness depends on how many get externally linked.  Most individual document don't get external links.   If yours are of high value they may get linked more.    If you do find that one is externally linked you could simply rename it.  Or you could create a script that renames your entire secret directory weekly and changes all the links on your site.

Comment: Renaming these files seems a bit drastic and possibly annoying for legitimate users. Presumably it would be OK for users to add personal bookmarks? A bit of an aside, but I would be utterly amazed if Google Scholar did not honour the `X-Robots-Tag` header. There is no special google-scholar-bot, at least there is nothing listed on the [Google Crawlers](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943?hl=en) page.