# How to prevent a specific PDF file from being indexed by search engines in Wordpress?

Tags: htaccess, search-engine-indexing

In a wordpress multisite installation, I would like to block indexing of a specific pdf file using HTTP X-Robots-Tag response header using htaccess file.

Any of the indications found in previous related questions (i.e. [this one](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/14520/how-to-prevent-a-pdf-file-from-being-indexed-by-search-engines)) didn't work in my case.

I used the instructions but all checks and every online checkers don't shows the headers I'd need

These are my htaccess configs
[image: my htaccess configs]

These are real headers in browser inspector
[image]

Comment: Which `.htaccess` file did you put that config in?   The document root?  `wp-content/`? `wp-content/uploads/`?

Comment: I'm not sure I trust the browser inspector to show headers.  I've never seen headers embedded in HTML like that before.   Even if they are legit, it could be using a cached copy from before you added the htaccess rule.    I tend to test using [curl](https://curl.se/) on the command line like `curl --head http://example.com/xxxxxxx/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/2020/11/Xxxxxxxxxxxxx.pdf`

Comment: Also, did you disallow the pdf in `robots.txt`?  If so, it doesn't matter what your headers are because Googlebot will never crawl it and see the headers.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller the htaccess file is the one in the directory of the multisite wp installation. I mean it is in /nameoffolder/ while the pdf file is in /nameoffolder/wp-content/uploads/sites/......

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I've just tried also with curl obtaining the same headers

Comment: "I've never seen headers embedded in HTML like that before." - This would seem to be the "HTML output (Elements)" when "inspecting" the PDF in Chrome's built-in PDF viewer. I think this output is "unique"(?) to the PDF viewer (or plugins?). It would be preferable to use the "Network" tab in the _Browser Inspector_ and refresh the content with the Inspector open (and cache disabled).

Comment: @StephenOstermiller yes, i already disallowed the pdf in _robots.txt_

Comment: @bobrock4 You should not disallow the pdf in `robots.txt` (which is basically what Stephen is saying).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<Files>` directive only applies to *filenames*, not file-paths, so your `<Files>` directive will never match and the header will not be set.

To set this header on a specific file (and not all `.pdf` files - as in the linked question/answers) in the root `.htaccess` file then you can set an environment variable when this file is requested and conditionally set the header based on this env var.

For example:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "/path/to/example.pdf" NOINDEX
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow" env=NOINDEX
```

Alternatively, if you could place an additional `.htaccess` file in the directory that contains the PDF file you want to target, then you could use a `<Files>` directive in that `.htaccess` file:

```
<Files "example.pdf">
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
</Files>
```

You could use this same method in the root `.htaccess` file, but it will also add the header to *all* `example.pdf` file requests on the system - although it's probably unlikely you have more than one file with the same name anyway I would think, so this may be the better solution after all.

Comment: could this htaccess in the folder containing only the instruction _<Files......../Files>_ ? Anything else?

Comment: Yes, just the `<Files>....</Files>` container as mentioned above. I've removed the `env=` argument from that header directive - sorry, copy/paste error!