# How to fix "no user selected canonical" on downloadable file

Tags: canonical-url

I have a pdf file liked to page.  This can be downloaded.

```html
<a rel="noopener" target="_blank" title="opens in new window" href="https://example.com/files/CertainTeed_ASNZS4020_PASS.PDF">Sample Certificate</a>
```

GSE is telling me

> Page Indexing Issue
>
> Duplicate without user-selected canonical

How can I stop it from thinking that it's a webpage ?  I am thinking of adding a `nofollow` to the `rel` attribute

Comment: Does it have the same content as some other page or document?

Comment: No, there are no duplicate pages and no duplicate links or duplicate files on my site.  But there could be a copy of that pdf on another site (not mine).  I just need it to be not indexed.

Comment: There is a solution for that here: [How to prevent a PDF file from being indexed by search engines?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/14520/how-to-prevent-a-pdf-file-from-being-indexed-by-search-engines)

Comment: Mine is obviously a duplicate then.  Shall I delete it, or does it have a value being here ?

Comment: No need to delete.  Marking it a duplicate will create a signpost for anybody that searches and finds your question.